# Invalid column name 'rn' in CTN expression and recursive query (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I'm not new to SQL, but never did any complex queries with analytics etc. Thus I did some googling and came up with this:

```
with timePeriods as ( -- sort time frames according to EARLY_START_DATE per task
 select
  TASK_ID, FULLPATHNAME, EARLY_START_DATE, EARLY_END_DATE,
  ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by FULLPATHNAME order by EARLY_START_DATE, EARLY_END_DATE) as rn
 from SQLTable
), cte as ( -- SQL recursive CTE expression
 select -- anchor query
  TASK_ID, FULLPATHNAME, EARLY_START_DATE, EARLY_END_DATE, rn, 1 as GroupId
 from timePeriods
 where rn = 1

 union all

 select -- recursive sql query
  p2.TASK_ID,
  p1.FULLPATHNAME,
  case
  when (p1.EARLY_START_DATE between p2.EARLY_START_DATE and p2.EARLY_END_DATE) then p2.EARLY_START_DATE
  when (p2.EARLY_START_DATE between p1.EARLY_START_DATE and p1.EARLY_END_DATE) then p1.EARLY_START_DATE
  when (p1.EARLY_START_DATE < p2.EARLY_START_DATE and p1.EARLY_END_DATE > p2.EARLY_END_DATE) then p1.EARLY_START_DATE
  when (p1.EARLY_START_DATE > p2.EARLY_START_DATE and p1.EARLY_END_DATE < p2.EARLY_END_DATE) then p2.EARLY_START_DATE
  else p2.EARLY_START_DATE
  end as EARLY_START_DATE,

  case
  when (p1.EARLY_END_DATE between p2.EARLY_START_DATE and p2.EARLY_END_DATE) then p2.EARLY_END_DATE
  when (p2.EARLY_END_DATE between p1.EARLY_START_DATE and p1.EARLY_END_DATE) then p1.EARLY_END_DATE
  when (p1.EARLY_START_DATE < p2.EARLY_START_DATE and p1.EARLY_END_DATE > p2.EARLY_END_DATE) then p1.EARLY_END_DATE
  when (p1.EARLY_START_DATE > p2.EARLY_START_DATE and p1.EARLY_END_DATE < p2.EARLY_END_DATE) then p2.EARLY_END_DATE
  else p2.EARLY_END_DATE
  end as EARLY_END_DATE,

  p2.rn,
  case when
  (p1.EARLY_START_DATE between p2.EARLY_START_DATE and p2.EARLY_END_DATE) or
  (p1.EARLY_END_DATE between p2.EARLY_START_DATE and p2.EARLY_END_DATE) or
  (p1.EARLY_START_DATE < p2.EARLY_START_DATE and p1.EARLY_END_DATE > p2.EARLY_END_DATE) or
  (p1.EARLY_START_DATE > p2.EARLY_START_DATE and p1.EARLY_END_DATE < p2.EARLY_END_DATE)
  then
  p1.GroupId
  else
  (p1.GroupId+1)
  end as GroupId
 from cte p1 -- referencing CTE itself
 inner join SQLTable p2
  on p1.FULLPATHNAME = p2.FULLPATHNAME and
  (p1.rn+1) = p2.rn
)
select * from cte order by FULLPATHNAME, rn
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is to group records overlapping by time periods. Unfortunately I'm getting this error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 47
Invalid column name 'rn'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 33
Invalid column name 'rn'.
```

My question may appear a bit stupid but it seems like some typo and any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `join SQLTable p2` .. `p2.rn` looks like  `SQLTable` has no `rn` column.

Answer (score 0):

In the recursive part of the query, you have:

```
 from cte p1 join-- referencing CTE itself
      SQLTable p2
      on p1.FULLPATHNAME = p2.FULLPATHNAME and
         (p1.rn + 1) = p2.rn
```

However, you defined `rn` in `TimePeriods` -- and there would not seem to be any such column in `SQLTable`.  I assume you want to refer to your CTE:

```
 from cte p1 join-- referencing CTE itself
      TimePeriods p2
      on p1.FULLPATHNAME = p2.FULLPATHNAME and
         (p1.rn + 1) = p2.rn
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, yes that was it - wrong reference - I should have been refer to CTE above. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user16259849 . . . I have made exactly this mistake more than once ;)